# Changing UI elements while scrolling

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I have a Layout with a ToggleButton and a gallery.

I'd like to change the toggleButton when I'm scrolling, I've implemented OnItemeSelectedListener and depending of the object I'm setting the button checked or not.

The thing is that the scroll freezes when the ToggleButton is changing, I know that there is only one thread for the UI but  could I improve it?

I've seen apps like the CNN one which changes items like a textView color while scrolling, so should be a way...

Comment: can you post some code to guide the answers to be specific...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the ToggleButton, I can change drawables, textviews and other items whitout problems but it seems that ToggleButton.setChecked is a slow code.

Finally I have two ToggleButtons overlapped, one to on and the other one to off and I make the top one visible or invisible.. apparently it's the same and it faster now :).